# Python - Redefining class attribute in a derived class

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose I have a base class, where there's a `__flag` attribute accessible by a `@classmethod`.

```
class Base(object):
    __flag = None

    def __init__(self) :
        pass

    @classmethod
    def flag(self):
        return self.__flag
```

Suppose I also have a derived class where I change the attribute.

```
class Derived(Base):
    __flag = True
```

Then, when I try to access the attribute of the derived class, I get the attribute of the base class:

```
In [3]: print Derived.flag()
None
```

Why? I really can not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `__` from `__flag` and it will work nicely. Like so:

```
class Base(object):
    flagAtt = None

    def __init__(self) :
       pass

    @classmethod
    def flag(self):
        return self.flagAtt

class Derived(Base):
    flagAtt = True
```

Which gives:

```
>>> print Derived.flag()
True
>>> print Base.flag()
None
```

Comment: Oh, it's as simple as that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This is because the "hidden" variables in Python get stored differently. There's a tiny bit of magic there.

Here's an example of why it does not work:

```
class Base(object):
    __flag = 'base'
    _other_flag = 'base'

    def __init__(self) :
        pass

    @classmethod
    def flag(self):
        return self.__flag

    @classmethod
    def other_flag(self):
        return self._other_flag

class Derived(Base):
    __flag = 'derived'
    _other_flag = 'derived'

print 'base flag', Base.flag()
print 'derived flag', Derived.flag()
print 'base other flag', Base.other_flag()
print 'derived other flag', Derived.other_flag()

# Note the following 2 statements:
print 'base flag property', Derived._Base__flag
print 'derived flag property', Derived._Derived__flag

print 'base other flag property', Base._other_flag
print 'derived other flag property', Derived._other_flag
```

As you can see at the bottom, it's stored in a different variable and silently translated to that within the `Base.flag` method.

Answer (score 1):

Python performs name-mangling on variables that start with two underscores (except those that *also* end with two underscores), so `__flag` in `Base` is different from `__flag`. You can observe this by using `dir`:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     __flag = True
... 
>>> dir(Base)
['_Base__flag', '__class__', '__delattr__', ......   # lots of others
```

The `__flag` variable is turned into `_Base__flag` here. In `Derived` it is turned into `_Derived__flag`, so you are not actually overriding anything, just introducing a new variable.

If you want a variable to be overridable, do **not** use names staring with two underscores.